# How to set gitlab environment based on rules?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a job in gitlab ci/cd defined:

```
authenticate:


stage: authenticate
  image: google/cloud-sdk:debian_component_based
  variables:
    ENVIRONMENT: staging
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"
      when: always
      variables:
        ENVIRONMENT: production
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "staging"
      when: always
      variables:
        ENVIRONMENT: staging
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "development"
      when: always
      variables:
        ENVIRONMENT: development
  environment:
    name: $ENVIRONMENT
```

I cannot set gitlab environment, because when i push to development branch, $CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME is staging instead of development